# Как использовать middleware через api?

Tags: php, laravel

Файл api.php:

```
   $api->version('v1', function ($api) {
      $api->get('todos', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TodoController@index');
      $api->post('todos', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TodoController@store');
      //ну и так далее
});
```

как использовать middleware для проверки залогинен ли юзер когда он пытается зайти в админку через api ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если допустить, что вы используете пакет `dingo/api`, то вот, что говорит [документация](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Creating-API-Endpoints):

```
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'foo'], function ($api) {
  // маршруты
});
```

Где `foo` - middleware, которое проверяет залогинен ли пользователь.